# uiwait color button - Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this small Matlab code:

```
uiwait(warndlg('Try 1.  Click OK to continue'));
uiwait(msgbox('Try 2'));
```

Is it possible to change the color of the OK button to another color (e.g., dark gray)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the OK button (and not of the message box), you need to access the `Children` of that message box first and change the `BackgroundColor` property. For a dark gray box I'll use the RGB triplet `[.2 .2 .2]`

Therefore:

```
hMsg=warndlg('Try 1.  Click OK to continue');

%// Get children
Children = get(hMsg,'Children');

%// The OK button is the 1st
OKButton = Children(1);

set(OKButton,'BackgroundColor',[.2 .2 .2])

uiwait(hMsg) %// Wait for button click; needed if you want code to stop. Thanks Jonas.
```

Output:

[image]

Of course doing it in one go yields the same result:

```
set(Children(1),'BackgroundColor',[.2 .2 .2])
```

Comment: Note that the code as written here will not stop - you need to add the `uiwait(hMsg)` call at the end.

Comment: Benoit_11 I've posted my answer without refreshing the page so I did not see your answer. I can delete it if you think is improper. Sorry about that

Comment: thanks @Jonas I'll edit the answer I forgot about that.

Answer (score 0):

To change the color of the `warndlg` pushbutton you have to first get the `handle` of the pushbutton.

To get the `handle` of the pushbutton you need the `handle` of the `warndlg`.

To get the handle of the of the `warndlg` you need to modify your code as follows:

```
% Create the warning dialog figure and get its handle
h=warndlg('Try 1.  Click OK to continue')
% Find the warning dialog figure pushbutton handle
wh=findobj(h,'style','pushbutton')
% Set the pushbutton background color to "dark gray"
set(wh,'BackgroundColor',[.5 .5 .5])
% Set the pushbutton foreground color to "white"
set(wh,'foregroundColor',[1 1 1])
% Call uiwait for the warning dialog figur
uiwait(h)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

try the function set(hMsg, 'color', 'white');